# HTACCESS check if a language is set

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have seen multiple similar questions in SO already, but never specific enough to solve my problem, or not even close to what I really want to achieve. In short:

I have a multi-language website `www.domain.com`
If I go to the "contact" page, it will change to `www.domain.com/contact`
My HTACCESS changes this to `www.domain.com?page=contact`
When I enter a subpage on the contact page, let's say "manager" it changes to `www.domain.com/contact/manager` which HTACCESS changes to `www.domain.com?page=contact&subpage=manager`

This is working all fine. But now I want to implement languages. Here is what i want to achieve:

```
<if first parameter = (EN|FR|DE enz)> <-- HOW?
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/*([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/*([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/*$ 
index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&subpage=$3 [QSA,L]
</if>
<else>
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/*([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/*([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/*$ 
index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [QSA,L]
</else>
```

How should the first line be? No tutorial helped. I am a noob in HTACCESS, which might explain why I can't find a fitting solution. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you paste your current .htaccess in question

Comment: Sorry, while I keep trying I am overwriting the not working file, however, if was almost exactly as the one I posted in my question. Nothing from tutorials enz is working. I am aware that the problem could be in rewriteCond as well, but I have no idea what is possible there. The documentation is just too hard to understand from zero. :(

Comment: Is language just 2 digit language code or full language name?

Comment: just a two digit language code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use separates rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&subpage=$3 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It looks logical to me, i gonna try this out in a few hours, and will reply as soon as I can. I thank you in advance! I have been stuck for a few days now.

Comment: Working like a charm! Thanks! I gonna look into it so i can understand better what exactly is in the HTACCESS.